# Javascript Short function to check if value start and end date is bonded with each other

Tags: javascript, arrays

I am writing a simple solution where i can find if the value in multiple array like start date is start on next day of previous end date and return false if there is any gap between the start and end date

```
[{
"startDate": "2021-06-01 00:00:00",
"endDate": "2021-06-18 00:00:00",
 },
{
"startDate": "2021-06-19 00:00:00",
"endDate": "2021-07-05 00:00:00",
}
{
"startDate": "2021-07-09 00:00:00",
"endDate": "2021-07-15 00:00:00",
}]
```

Thanks

Comment: what simple solution have you come up with so far? Please share your work

Comment: Convert the first `endDate` to a `Date`. Add 1 to that date and see if it matches the next `startDate`.

Answer (score 0):

I am using this but need to find more clear answer.`

```
const dates = [{
"startDate": "2021-06-01 00:00:00",
"endDate": "2021-06-18 00:00:00",
 },
{
"startDate": "2021-06-19 00:00:00",
"endDate": "2021-07-05 00:00:00",
},
{
"startDate": "2021-07-09 00:00:00",
"endDate": "2021-07-15 00:00:00",
}]

const matchedFirstStartSecondDateEndDate = dates.filter((element,index) => {
            if(sortedSAs[index+1]) {
                return moment(element.endDate).diff(moment(dates[index+1].startDate), "days") != -1;
            }
        });
```

`